# In the bounty primary window, "learn more" link should be separated from the main sentence

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, bounties, spelling

When you click "start a bounty" link, the sentence saying how many bounties you can start is not separated with the following "learn more" link:

> [image]

Probably put a comma or a semicolon between the sentence and the link? Or just make them be two separate sentences.

Comment: (Or parenthetical)

Comment: Reported on [ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12998/176217) as well.

Comment: Yep, this (along with the use of lowercase for everything) is definitely an artifact of the older design philosophy that SE seemed to use early on in the network's existence. I'm guessing this part of the design just hasn't been touched in ages.